# Laravel foreach in one item?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

i have a relationship like

```
+------------+---------+
|    id      | problem |
+------------+---------+
| 1          | problem |    
+------------+---------+


+------------+----------+---------+
|    id      | problemid|solution |
+------------+----------+---------+
| 1          |  1       |solution1|    
+------------+----------+---------+
| 2          |  1       |solution2| 
+------------+----------+---------+
```

I have done a join and the problem is when i do a foreach in the view i get 2 items with the same problem and 2 different solutions but i need to get the same problem (one problem) and 2 solutions. How can i do it?

Here is the code in Controller:

```
$problem=Problem::select()
            ->join('solution','problem.id','=','solution.problemid')
            ->where('problem.id',$id)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Use [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) to do this more elegant

Comment: @JiFus i have do it already but i have there another problem that's what i am using join.

Comment: if your main point of interest is problem, with associated solutions, i think you should be doing where 'problem.id' not where 'solution.id'.  But obviously that will make no difference if you only have one record in problem.

Comment: how do u get two different solutions when u are using solution.id in where conditions


answer to ur question will be use problem.id in where condition

Comment: @mwal my mistake , in my query i have problem.id i edit it.

Comment: @Jigs1212 i edit it, in my query i use problem.id

Comment: best option would be to use with.

Comment: @Jigs1212 what do you mean ?

Comment: Use relations on model. Like in problem model us has many solutions, and use with in eloquent query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the Solution and i am using in View:

```
@foreach ($problem as $probl)
    @if ($loop->first)
        Here i put the code for fist item
    @endif

@endforeach
```

For another persons that are searching for same question here is documentation :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 1):

```
$problem=Problem::select()
            ->leftjoin('solution','problem.id','=','solution.problemid')
            ->where('solution.id',$id)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: i am still getting the same thing i have one collection and 2 items but i need one item because i have the same name of the problem and when i do an foreach i am getting ([problem1 solution1],[problem1, solution2]) but i need ([problem1, solution1,solution2])